# Знак препинания после "ещё"

Tags: пунктуация

**А ещё сегодня 12-е число и сейчас 2012 год.**

Обособляется ли в данном случае "а ещё"? Имеется ли такая возможность?

Как я вижу вариации этого предложения:

*А еще: сегодня 12-е число и сейчас 2012 год. (При таком обособлении выделяются однородные члены предложения.)*

*А еще сегодня 12-е число, и* (в значении *а*) *сейчас 2012 год.*

Или я не прав, и запятая не ставится нигде?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не обособляется. Здесь *а еще* союз.

В каждой "вариации" допущена ошибка: 1) двоеточие не нужно и 2) запятая перед *и* (который, кстати, в значении союза *и*) лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1.** А ещё **сегодня** 12-е число, и **сейчас** 2012 год.

Это ССП (состоит из двух простых предложений эллиптического типа), каждое предложение начинается с временного наречия, и это препятствует их объединению в одну фразу. Поэтому делается пауза, ставится запятая.

Сравнить: **А ещё сегодня  12-е число  и 2012 год.**

**Вариант 2.** А ещё: сегодня 12-е число, и **сейчас** 2012 год. **Авторская пунктуация**, запятая ставится при наличии паузы.