# Ставить ли запятую в предложении с «а ещё»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Скажите, нужно поставить запятую в предложении или нет (куда, не знаю)?
*А ещё у меня появился кот!*

Answer (score 1):

Если слово ["ещё"](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5) в этом предложении выступает в роли наречия, имеет значение *дополнительно, вдобавок к тому же* (похоже, что так оно и есть) и в предыдущем контексте не использовалось, то запятая не нужна.

**А ещё у меня появился кот!**
Примеры:
*А еще у меня большой прорыв в науке!* (Д. Рубина);
*А еще у меня несколько водочных бутылок ― может, возьмете?* (Е. Пищикова);
*А еще у меня мечта — чтобы над каждым оставшимся в Косово и Метохии сербским поселением взял шефство какой-нибудь российский город* (Ю. Нерсесов);
*А ещё у меня есть лучшая подруга* (П. Потапова).

С особенностями пунктуации, связанными с "еще", можно ознакомиться на нашем сайте:
[Знак препинания после "ещё"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428246/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91);
[Запятая после "и еще"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457340/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5).